# Why it is not modified to call multiple times strategy.exit on the PineScript

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I have created a Strategy with the Pinescript in the TradingView .

```
Some code ....
minlow = math.min(low[1],low[2],low[3])
maxhigh = math.min(high[1],high[2],high[3])
if time >= timestamp(year=startDate,month=1,day=1)
    if n > 0
        if dir
            strategy.entry("MyBuy",strategy.long,shares)
            if limitedProfit
                strategy.exit(id="BExit",from_entry = "MyBuy",stop=minlow,limit=close+(close-minlow)*ratio)
        if dir == false and fixed == false
            strategy.close("MySell")
    if n < 0
        if dir == false
            strategy.entry("MySell",strategy.short,shares)
            if limitedProfit
                strategy.exit(id="SExit",from_entry = "MySell",stop=maxhigh,limit=close-(maxhigh-close)*ratio)

        if dir and fixed == false
            strategy.close("MyBuy")
```

The line  `strategy.exit(id="BExit",from_entry = "MyBuy",stop=minlow,limit=close+(close-minlow)*ratio)` was called on each bar, But the stop was always the `minlow` to call `strategy.exit` first time.

It is the result i want, but i don't understand why it isn't modify to call `strategy.exit` mutiple times.

I need a reason why it is thus

Comment: if strategy is called several times, and stop/limit parameters are changed, then you can modify the order. But you need to check whether your conditions in which `strategy.extit()` call is plased are met.

Comment: You can place some `var` variable inside same scope with strategy.exit, and iterate it. Plot this variable to know how many times this scope was executed